# Installing PHP 7.0.0RC2 with mysqli on Raspberry Pi B

Tags: mysqli, raspberry-pi, php-7

Last week I installed PHP 7.0.0RC2 on my Raspberry Pi B.
I am able to view PHP pages, however, the problem is that I cannot connect to the database using mysqli (I know that mysql is no longer supported in PHP v7).

I ran the `./configure` command with `--with-mysqli=shared`.
However, when I check which modules are installed using the `php -m` command, I do not see mysqli.

I tried adding `extension=mysqli.so` to the php.ini file.
It first complained that the mysqli.so file could not be found, so I tried copying the mysqli.so of my php5 version to the extensions folder.
However, this did not solve the problem and resulted in the following error message:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20141001/mysqli.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20141001/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init in Unknown on line 0

Does anyone got any suggestions of how to get mysqli to work with my PHP7 installation on my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Did you follow any tutorial for installation of PHP7?

Comment: @Machavity I am running Raspbian 7.8 as OS.

Comment: @blarg I did not follow any particular tutorial for PHP 7, but I Googled how to install older versions of PHP (v5) from source.

Answer (score 1):

You may find detailed information in the `configure` output, but it's pretty hard to catch, and if it's not a fatal error, won't stop the build going ahead when you `make`.

The recommended (read: only decent) driver for MySQLi is the MySQL Native Driver (mysqlnd).

If you want MySQLi to be built shared, you must also build mysqlnd shared, and everything that depends on it (PDO MySQL, for example).

It's going to be simpler to just build the native drivers static, using the configure option:

```
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd
```

Which will enable a static build of mysqlnd and mysqli.

If for some reason you really do want to build shared, then you'll need configure options that closely resemble, if not are exactly the same as:

```
--enable-mysqlnd=shared
--with-mysqli=shared,mysqlnd
```

Which will result in a shared build of mysqlnd and mysqli, requiring you to add `extension=mysqlnd.so` and `extension=mysqli.so` in the appropriate order (the latter depends on the former), in the appropriate place.

Remember to `make distclean` before you re-configure the build, surprising things will happen if you do not ;)

Comment: I tried building with the option --with-mysqli=mysqlnd and I did a make distclean before reconfiguring the build, however I recevied the same error message as before

Comment: Somtimes ```make distclean``` is ineffective, try ```vcsclean```, verify it is no longer being built shared.